# plyr outperforms dplyr and data.table - What's wrong?

Tags: r, performance, data.table, dplyr, plyr

I have to apply a function to every row of a large table (~ 2M rows). I used to use `plyr` for that, but the table is growing continuously and the current solution starts to approach unacceptable runtimes. I thought I could just switch to `data.table` or `dplyr` and all is fine, but that's not the case.

Here's an example:

```
library(data.table)
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

dt = data.table("ID_1" = c(1:1000), # unique ID
                "ID_2" = ceiling(runif(1000, 0, 100)), # other ID, duplicates possible
                "group" = sample(LETTERS[1:10], 1000, replace = T), 
                "value" = runif(1000),
                "ballast1" = "X", # keeps unchanged in derive_dt
                "ballast2" = "Y", # keeps unchanged in derive_dt
                "ballast3" = "Z", # keeps unchanged in derive_dt
                "value_derived" = 0)
setkey(dt, ID_1)
extra_arg = c("A", "F", "G", "H")
```

ID_1 is guaranteed to contain no duplicates. Now I define a function to apply to every row/ID_1:

```
derive = function(tmprow, extra_arg){
  if(tmprow$group %in% extra_arg){return(NULL)} # exlude entries occuring in extra_arg
  group_index = which(LETTERS == tmprow$group)
  group_index = ((group_index + sample(1:26, 1)) %% 25) + 1
  new_group = LETTERS[group_index]
  if(new_group %in% unique(dt$group)){return(NULL)}
  new_value = runif(1)
  row_derived = tmprow
  row_derived$group = new_group
  row_derived$value = runif(1)
  row_derived$value_derived = 1
  return(row_derived)
}
```

This one doesn't do anything useful (the actual one does). The point is that the function takes one row and computes a new row of the same format.

Now the comparison:

```
set.seed(42)
system.time(result_dt <- dt[, derive(.SD, extra_arg), by = ID_1])
set.seed(42)
system.time(result_dplyr <- dt %>% group_by(ID_1) %>% do(derive(., extra_arg)))
set.seed(42)
system.time(results_plyr <- x <- ddply(dt, .variable = "ID_1", .fun = derive, extra_arg))
```

`plyr` is about 8x faster than both `data.table` and `dplyr`. Obviously I'm doing something wrong here, but what?

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to eddi's answer I could reduce runtimes for `data.table` and `dplyr` to ~ 0.6 and 0.8 of the `plyr` version, respectively. I intialized `row_derived` as data.frame: `row_derived = as.data.frame(tmprow)`. That's cool, but I still expected a higher performance increase from these packages...any further suggestions?

Comment: you are using data.frame syntax against data.table so you should not expect to get data.table speed :) as pointed by eddi you should look for vectorizing your solution, currently you are basically looping `derive` over `ID_1`.

Comment: @jangorecki: You mean modifying one column at a time? I doubt that's feasible in my case.

Comment: I mean using `$<-` and not using `:=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is the assignment you use has a very high overhead in `data.table`, and `plyr` converts the row to a `data.frame` before passing to your `derive` function, and thus avoids it:

```
library(microbenchmark)

df = as.data.frame(dt)

microbenchmark({dt$group = dt$group}, {df$group = df$group})
#Unit: microseconds
#                        expr      min       lq       mean    median       uq      max neval
# {     dt$group = dt$group } 1895.865 2667.499 3092.38903 3080.3620 3389.049 4984.406   100
# {     df$group = df$group }   26.045   45.244   64.13909   61.6045   79.635  157.266   100
```

I can't suggest a good fix, since you say your example is not real problem, so no point in solving it better. Some basic suggestions to look at are - vectorizing the code, and using `:=` or `set` instead (depending on what exactly you end up doing).

Comment: Ok, that's something to start with. Thanks!